# Usb key with no file system (raw space)?

Tags: io, filesystems, usb

I am wondering if it is possible to have a usb key in a raw format and still read/write files on it.

It should be cross-platform and understood by a dedicated software we ship.

I am kind of creating a **non-bootable** file system **in a hurry**, and I just need to read/write some values at some offsets on this raw storage space.

People who will use it will be shipped the software able to read those values (**not the operating system who will surely see raw/free space, but we don't care about that**).

Will I run into troubles with the mounting, or whatever?
Or is it green light?

Thanks

Comment: I guess I will have to treat it like a file and make my seeks like I want, and that should be about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, you can read and write the "unformatted" SD card or USB memory. You can also format it to whatever filesystem you need by writing to pages of that memory. The only possible difficulty is that the OS (at least later Windows versions) might not allow writing to the disk if the user account doesn't have admin rights.

Comment: That is an issue. So a normal user won't be able to save anything to the usb from the Qt program? If that is confirmed, that is a real issue.

Comment: @Larry Depends on the OS and access rights of the user account. Windows does have some restrictions on writing to the disk not via file APIs. Our RawDisk product helps one overcome those restrictions on Windows Vista and later, but you need an admin account to install the driver. On Linux the situation might be different, I don't know.

Comment: thanks for your invaluable input. I will check your product by the way.